# Decoding facebook's blob video url

Tags: facebook, blob, decode

I found `blob:https://www.facebook.com/c7e5a634-2343-4464-a03e-4a1987301ca1` video source on Facebook's private group and I really can't download the video by entering the url nor am I able to decode. Is there any way to decode this?

```html
<video height="274" width="476" preload="auto" style="" class="_ox1 _21y0 _1_d1" data-video-width="476" data-video-height="274" data-original-aspect-ratio="1.7387058423913" id="u_0_27" src="blob:https://www.facebook.com/dc89feae-5b46-4103-8ee9-da7d7630ca94"></video>
```

Answer (score 239, accepted):

**This method will get the video and its audio AS SEPARATE FILES.** The downloaded video will have no sound, but you will be able to download its audio file and connect it to the video in some video editing program if you need to.

1. In **Google Chrome**, go to **Facebook**.
2. Open the **Chrome Developer Tools (F12)**.
3. Go to the **Network** tab in the Developer Tools (it's at the top of the Developer Tools window) [image: Network tab]
4. Play the video you would like to download on Facebook. Let it play for a few seconds and **look at the Network tab** during that. Long strings of numbers will appear every couple of seconds. [image]
5. Right click one of those strings, then go Copy>Copy link address
   [image]
6. Paste (CTRL+V) the link you copied somewhere (eg Notepad) and remove "**&bytestart=3684046&byteend=3862768**" from the end.

   So I have a link like:

   > https://scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t66.18014-6/46772657_738781116188283_6399514850013601801_n.mp4?_nc_cat=107&efg=4yJ7ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImRhc2hfb2VwX2hxMl9mcmFnXzJfdmlkZW8ifQ%3D%3D&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-xx&oh=91a5abdd5608768a05fd884773a45802&oe=5C29B042
   > &bytestart=3684046&byteend=3862768

   After you cut the bold part out, the link that points to the full .mp4 or .webm of the video is:

   > https://scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t66.18014-6/46772657_738781116188283_6399514850013601801_n.mp4?_nc_cat=107&efg=4yJ7ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImRhc2hfb2VwX2hxMl9mcmFnXzJfdmlkZW8ifQ%3D%3D&_nc_ht=scontent-waw1-xx&oh=91a5abdd5608768a05fd884773a45802&oe=5C29B042
7. Open the modified link, right click the video inside and select "Save video as..." [image: Right click video to save-as]

**Sometimes, when you open the link you may get just the audio of the video instead of the video itself.**
That's because Facebook downloads the audio and video separately. Just try repeating steps 5-7 with a different string of numbers till you get it right. Instructions to reduce the chance of accidentally picking an audio link are below.

If you need to download many videos and don't want to guess whether your link points to audio or video, type `larger-than: 50k` (or more) in the **Filter field** in the Network tab. You can also click the **XHR** button in Filters so it doesn't show non-video files like FB images.

[image: Helpful filters for Chrome to show only video links]

Comment: For a high quality video, play the video in fullscreen before grabbing the link.

Comment: Best of the best. Thank you!! I used this to download a video I attached in a comment! There was no way of downloading it, but this!!

Comment: `Sometimes, when you open the link you may get just the audio of the video instead of the video itself. That's because Facebook downloads the audio and video separately.` This happens for me, what now?

Comment: @Prometheus I edited my answer. Pick a different string of numbers in the Network tab to copy the link from.

Comment: suprisingly i grabbed just the video alone no audio

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Same here, no request contained both so far -- each time it's either audio or video.

Comment: I updated the answer to clarify what this solution does.

Comment: To merge the video and audio, you can use ffmpeg like that: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4`.
Reference: https://superuser.com/a/277667

Comment: This works in Firefox too. At least the video, I didn't try audio.

Comment: This did not work for me in Chrome or Brave. On step 4, I didn't see a number string for an MP4, only JPEGs from elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 20):

You can download an FB video in a chrome browser with no plugins / other software required. (As long as you are logged into FB and have permission to view the video).

1. open up  the video and r.click for Get Video URL (copy it) -if you have the option "Copy URL at current time", use that option instead of "Show video URL"
2. paste that address into another tab and replace the www with m e.g. https://m.facebook.com/MusicIsMagico/videos/2645908645633407/?t=0
3. play the video, while it's playing open the dev tools and go to the elements tab
4. search for mp4 till you find a source address that's inside the
   video tags  - which will be inside a div that also contains another address with forward slashes and .mp4 in it.
   e.g. 
   [image: FB video URL]

   https://video.fmel5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t42.9040-2/10000000_1804934796220974_2070197824632389632_n.mp4?_nc_cat=1`&`amp;efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InN2ZV9zZCJ9`&`amp;oh=785f223b80388c820f79b9a49c1dfc39`&`amp;oe=5B73B10B
5. copy this source address. When you copy the address, chrome (if that's what you are using) does the html replacement for the ampersand characters. You will need to put them back. So replace the "& a m p ;" (< had to space that so it doesn't get converted here) separators in the address with just & - use notepad find and replace or something ) and paste in another tab. Drop any parts of the URL that have frame sizing etc.. so you address should look like this:

https://video.fmel5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t42.9040-2/10000000_1804934796220974_2070197824632389632_n.mp4?_nc_cat=1&efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InN2ZV9zZCJ9&oh=5f241d3c08d5c819b0c3810d0e21d73b&oe=5B73BF1B

- this will load
  your browsers default html video player which has a download button

  - this will all only work if you are logged into FB and have permission to view the video (doesnt' work incognito)

Getting the right URL can take a bit of playing around but it works when you've got it right

[image]

Comment: You seem to have missed the entire point.  Downloading MP4 is easy.  There is no MP4 source, just a blob.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: Downvoted. The question is about FB `blob:` videos, not FB `https://video...` videos.

Answer (score 20):

Another alternative that worked in Firefox in Feb 2021:

- Open the post's permalink
- Change the page's URL - replace `www` with `m` and load that
- Now use Inspector to navigate down to the div containing the video object - and the video URL will be a direct link
- Copy-paste that URL into your browser, or create an anchor link to that URL and load your link and right-click to save destination.

It downloads as mp4 including video and audio.

### Update, 2 Jul 2021

When I followed my own steps today, pasting the mp4 URL returned a page giving the following error:

> Bad URL timestamp

However, I still found a work-around.

**Side note:** One of the containing divs has ID `mobile_injected_video_feed_pagelet`.

**Facebook now injects the video element when you hit the play button.**

That `VIDEO` element contains the URL you need. The URL does contain "MP4" in the path.

What I did was:

- Open Inspector
- **Hit "Play" on the video**
- While the video is playing, find the `VIDEO` element and copy the URL from the `VIDEO` element
- Paste that into a new tab
- The new tab would show a smaller thumbnail of the video
- Right-click the thumbnail and save the media to your PC

**You must hit play for the `VIDEO` element to appear in the page source.**

I'm using Firefox but any browser with an inspector should work.

Comment: For some reason I forgot this trick. FYI happily it also works in Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! The easiest solution

Comment: Hm.. Had to follow my own steps today, and now when I paste the MP4 link it comes back with "Bad URL timestamp". I find 8 instances of "mp4" in the page source. I haven't tested all yet. I do note one of the containing divs has ID "mobile_injected_video_feed_pagelet" - they might have changed their mobile approach to prevent access to the video file. Needs further investigation.

Comment: ... and found a solution - added it to the answer itself. In a nutshell: open inspector, find the `VIDEO` element, start playing the video and then copy the URL from that `VIDEO` element.

Comment: nice & easy. Still working in 2022

Answer (score 1):

I assemble [here](https://www.techandlifetips.com/tutorials/download-video-from-facebook-comment) the necessary steps from the different answers :

1. Facebook downloads the audio and the video separately, so get the
   audio link from the google chrome inspector, by right click on the
   video and choosing inspect ,going to Inspector, Network Tab, and
   checking the links, use filter:larger-than:50k in the filter area to
   select bigger files (change 50k according to the length of your
   video), look in the results for mp4 or wav links, remove
   **&bytestart=number_here &byteend =number_here** from the end of the
   link,  open it and download the audio
2. Get the video link from the google chrome inspector, using same
   steps above, open the link and download the video

Now in order to mix the audio and the video, we need to use ffmeg :

3. Download ffmpeg build for your OS from its website, use this link
4. Extract the downloaded zip file
5. Open your command line tool and cd  to :
   \Downloads\ffmpeg-2021-04-28-git-1ab74bc193-full_build\ffmpeg-2021-04-28-git-1ab74bc193-full_build\bin
   (change according to which version you downloaded)
6. Assume the input files are in the current folder, the output will be
   generated in the current folder too

   Mix the audio and the video with ffmpeg using command :
   **.\ffmpeg.exe  -i video.ext -i audio.ext -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4**

Answer (score 0):

Add this extension to your chrome browser to download FB videos:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-downloader-plus/njgehaondchbmjmajphnhlojfnbfokng

Once installed, go play the video and click the fb downloader icon (Downward Arrow icon) and choose your desired resolution.

Comment: But this one is facebook's private video

Comment: 404. That’s an error.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Blob Video Downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blob-video-downloader/knpbbcbpainepebaalgbehcidbkednfb) extension. It takes a few mins but it opens a new tab with a button to download video. I try it with a 1min video 720p.

Comment: Not really useful as the video and audio are separate

Comment: I didn't have this issue. But, it's easy to add audio with a free video editor program like windows 10 video editor.

Comment: You can just use ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

For video that is in this blob format

[image]

or other formats served by Facebook with the intent to hide the ability to download, you can try loading the page without Javascript. They will serve you a version that is compatible, which means directlink

[image]

Tested working 11-2020

[image]

Comment: Tried Feb 2021 - page loads nothing useful now.

Comment: @qkhanhpro How Facebook dowloder online tools work? I want to build a one from asp.net. Can you guide me? Where should I start... Thank you